# what is the meaning of 'int (*enqueue)(struct , struct)'

Tags: c, linux, kernel

all.
I am reading the source code of linux kernel and find one line which I do not understand:

> file: /net/sched/sch_generic.c

location: the definition of `struct Qdisc`:

```
struct Qdisc
{
    int             (*enqueue)(struct sk_buff *skb, struct Qdisc *dev);
    struct sk_buff *    (*dequeue)(struct Qdisc *dev);
    unsigned        flags;
#define TCQ_F_BUILTIN   1
#define TCQ_F_THROTTLED 2
#define TCQ_F_INGRESS   4
    int         padded;
    struct Qdisc_ops    *ops;
    u32         handle;
    u32         parent;
    atomic_t        refcnt;
```

....

what is the meaning of `int (*enqueue)(struct sk_buff *skb, struct Qdisc *dev)`

(first line)? Is `enqueue` a pointer?

Comment: [`int (*enqueue)(struct sk_buff *skb, struct Qdisc *dev);`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*enqueue%29%28struct+sk_buff+*%2C+struct+Qdisc+*%29%3B)

Comment: If you don't know what a function pointer is, you shouldn't be reading the Linux kernel source. Arguably, _nobody_ should be reading the Linux kernel source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int (*enqueue)(struct sk_buff *skb, struct Qdisc *dev)
```

`enqueue` is a pointer to a function that returns `int`and takes a pointer to `struct sk_buff` and a pointer to `struct Qdisc`.

Answer (score 2):

`enqueue` is a *pointer to a function* taking `(struct sk_buff *skb, struct Qdisc *dev)` and returning `int`.